# Close votes review bug when daily limit is reached

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, review-audits

SE site: http://magento.stackexchange.com

**Scenario:**
 - I'm reviewing the "close votes" section.
 - I only have one more close vote for today.
 - I choose to close the question I'm reviewing.

**Expected result**

- The vote get's registered.
- My review count increases by 1.
- I should see a confirmation in the history that I reviewed that question.
- I should see a message that I have no more close votes for today.

**Actual result**

- My vote actually gets registered.
  [image: close votes]
- My review **is not registered in the history** section (see screenshot for the last line in the history. The question I voted after that one was https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/37710/146)
  [image: not registered]
- My **review count does not get incremented**.  Sorry no screenshot for that.
- I get a message saying I have no more close votes for today. (this one is OK)

**Note:**
I was able to reproduce this 3 days in a row.

**[EDIT]**
I've searched a bit on this meta and I found out that this issue [was reported before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149284/224252) in 2012. The answer states it has been fixed. It wasn't.
I don't know if the problem reproduces on the specific site I mentioned only or is a general issue

Comment: We are seeing this problem in a [Stack Overflow chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/20038567#20038567), though it's only affecting this one user, AFAIK.

Comment: @gunr2171. I guess there are 2 of us now. Someone should fix it before it spreads. :)